# TweetSharp setting proxy server

Tags: asp.net, tweetsharp

How can I specify detailed proxy settings in TweetSharp? By this I mean in addition to the server name, details like Port, Username, Password etc? As of now the only parameter, is

```
Dim X as  New TwitterService(Key,Secret)
X.Proxy = "abcd"
```

Which accepts only a string, which I assume is the server name / IP Address.
My app is behind a corporate firewall and the proxy requires authentication and uses a custom port. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As I was completely unable to specify the authentication details for the proxy server, I was forced to come up with my own workaround. I installed ccproxy on the server, and had it cascade the authentication to the other proxy server.

This is working well as of now.